# Why is this jQuery submit event not triggering correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, search

I am trying to create a function that takes a user's input and uses it to search Wikipedia. Then, at least for now, show the first result by appending it to the  element call "#list".

I have tested the API, the JSON syntax, the appendTo syntax all independently and confirmed that they are working fine. But the event does not execute.

```
 $('form').submit(function(event) 
{
    var $input = $(event.target).find('input');
    var search = $input.val();

$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&titles=Main+Page&srsearch="+search+"&srprop=wordcount%7Ctimestamp%7Csnippet%7Ctitlesnippet", 
function(data) 
{  
var item = data.query.pages.search[0].titlesnippet;
var itemDesc = data.query.pages.search[0].snippet;
var html = $('<li>').html(item+"<br/>"+itemDesc);
          html.prependTo('#list');
});

});
```

Comment: If you console.log out search prior to the $.getJSON, does it return the correct value?

Comment: `$.ajax({url:"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&titles=Main+Page&srsearch="+search+"&srprop=wordcount%7Ctimestamp%7Csnippet%7Ctitlesnippet",dataType:'jsonp',success: r=>console.log(r)})` Can you try with this and let us konw if you see anything in the console?

Object {readyState: 1}

Comment: I think you are facing a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header issue.